# React - componentWillMount memory leak

Tags: reactjs, memory-leaks

I watched this video about `componentWillMount` can cause memory leak:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fgd2ivSnXXo

I tested it myself with checking for listeners by `console.log(TodoStore.listenerCount("change"));` but it seems there is no multiple listeners anymore.

Is this problem fixed by React or I am still supposted to use `componentWillUnmount()` to destroy listener?

Comment: `componentWillMount` is deprecated anyways. If you create a listener in `componentDidMount` or anywhere else, its good practice to do cleanup. this is much more apparent for dom  listeners like window resize or mousemove

Comment: What to use if not componentWillMount then? Also u not answered my question

Comment: use `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentWillMount` not causing memory leak anymore and it is reccomended to use `componentDidMount` as drop-in replacement, because `componentWillMount` is deprecated.